# How to store survey year in database

Tags: database-design

I am designing database for a survey web application. The survey is supposed to be conducted annually and people can take survey for past years by choosing year from drop down.

Database structure is like this

University table -> College (child table) -> Course (child table)

I need to issue queries like "find no of courses for a particular survey year".

Do I need to store survey year in all database tables (50+ tables), although it seems straight forward, but I am feeling that this is not a correct design (as the data is repeated). Please share your thoughts on this.

Thanks

Comment: can you include the table structure? Where is the survey data stored?

Comment: Tables contains information about university, college (having foreign key to university), courses (having foreign key to college). Data is stored in Postgres database.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is really unclear.. what do the tables look like? Is there a survey table? What is the relationship between a survey and university/college/course etc etc..

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to explain the question properly, there is no survey table, tables like university, college and courses store the information about survey. Like filling one survey form per university, to find out its colleges and courses. This can be though as data entry instead of survey, but the data is entered annually (like a survey).

Comment: You can also try posting this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/

Answer (score 0):

Go and read this article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.  The normal form you should aim for is the third normal form (3NF).  This will eliminate duplication of data.  You should be able to eliminate the survey year from all "child" tables.  However, if the survey year is part of the primary key on a parent table, you won't be able to eliminate the field from the child tables.  Rather use a single int field as the primary key, rather than a composite primary key with the survey year in it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand normalization and year is not a part of primary key. In theory I can store year on the parent table and use join queries to get results from child table based on year. But I have multi level child hierarchy using join tables and it will become practically very difficult to issue queries with multiple joins. I am trying to find some solution to link survey year with child tables.

Comment: Maybe then just a separate DB per year?

Comment: Yes, but user can fill form for past years. I am not sure how to maintain separate DB based on application logic. Thanks for your help.